# Section transclusion in Screwturn

Tags: screwturn

I'd like to transclude sections of pages. The internal links can reference sections (e.g. [page#section_1]), but it looks like you can only transclude full pages in Screwturn.

If so, is there a plugin that does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a transclude plug-in (never used it myself though) and you could try it by accessing the old screwturn site using web archive at:

[http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.Transclude-Files-Plugin.ashx](https://web.archive.org/web/20131022193017/http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.Transclude-Files-Plugin.ashx)

The markup instructions are on this page:

[http://fiala.cc/ScrewTurnWiki.Transclude-Files.ashx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120827035146/http://fiala.cc/ScrewTurnWiki.Transclude-Files.ashx)

And lastly, to download the plugin:

[http://fiala.cc/public/attachments/ScrewTurnWiki.Transclude-Files/Fiala.ScrewTurnWiki.TranscludeFiles.dll](https://web.archive.org/web/20131022193017/http://fiala.cc/public/attachments/ScrewTurnWiki.Transclude-Files/Fiala.ScrewTurnWiki.TranscludeFiles.dll)

Bear in mind that the plugin was for an older version of screwturn but I generally found them to be forward compatible.  Its worth a shot!  May want to try on a test install of screwturn through.  No warranties!  :)

Comment: I'm not sure of which markup to use to transclude a section of a wiki page, it seems to work with whole files.  
I have found this: 
http://scruwturn-plugins-ds.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/FormattingPlus/SectionTransclusion.cs
which appears to be a part of Stankovski.Wiki.FormattingPlus.dll:
https://code.google.com/p/scruwturn-plugins-ds/downloads/list

Comment: I can't work out the markup from the code to try it, however.